# Destroying a game object that's part of a prefab once an action key is pressed inside a trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'm making a 2d platform. My level is made up of a multiple platforms that are all part of a prefab. I want to make it so when my player presses a key (in this case 'E') inside of a collider2d the platform above the player is destroyed and the box resting on the platform falls down.

I've got the detection working for when 'E' is pressed inside of the trigger but can't figure out how to destroy just the single platform in the prefab.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class SwitchController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collider2D switchCollider;
    public Rigidbody2D player;

    void Start()
    {
        switchCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        // var player = col.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        var actionBtn = PlayerController.action;
        if (player)
        {
            Debug.Log("Collided");

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                actionBtn = true;
                Debug.Log("Action Pressed");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never destroy anything of a "Prefab" .. you probably mean to destroy a certain GameObject which is part of an Instantiated GameObject. What exactly is the issue? Somewhere you will have to define which is the GameObject reference you want to destroy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, the simplest solution would be to store the platform via the inspector (of the prefab).
Then you would destroy the game-object when needed, like so:

```
public class SwitchController : MonoBehaviour {

    // ...

    public GameObject targetPlatform;

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col) {
        // ...
        Destroy(targetPlatform); // Destroy the platform.
    }
}
```

**Or, you can raycast upwards from the player**

```
public class SwitchController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Collider2D switchCollider;
    public Rigidbody2D player;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("The layer mask of the platforms.")]
    public LayerMask platformLayerMask;
    void Start() {
        switchCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col) {
        var actionBtn = PlayerController.action;

        if (player) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
                actionBtn = true;
                // Raycast upwards from the player's location.
                // (Raycast will ignore everything but those with the same layermask as 'platformPlayerMask')
                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(player.transform.position, Vector2.up, Mathf.Infinity, platformLayerMask);

                if (hit.collider != null) {
                    // Destroy what it hits.
                    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compared to the first solution, this solution is more dynamic.
You just have to set the [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) of the platforms in the inspector.

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple! I went with the first option but will look into the second way once I get the the game working and have time to tweak it. Thanks Kaynn!